# Libreoffice Calc, macro set Text Alignment Indent, or property documentation?

Tags: macros, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

In Libreoffice Calc it is possible to use macro's to set the text properties of each cell, to format the layout and font. I was able to find some property names online, in code examples and forums.

```
oCell.CharHeight = 16
oCell.HoriJustify = com.sun.star.table.CellHoriJustify.CENTER
oCell.setPropertyValue("IsTextWrapped", True)
oCell.RotateAngle = 9000 ' rotate 90.00 degrees
' etc.
```

However, I can not find the macro code for some of the properties that are available in the GUI (right click, Format Cells). Specifically, I'm looking for macro code to set the "Text Alignment Indent" property.

I think I've found [some documentation here](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/DispatchCommands), as it mentions `.uno:AlignmentIndent` and `.uno:IncrementIndentValue` but I have no clue on how to use this in a macro. I've tried guessing the property names using AlignmentIndent, setPropertyValue("TextAlignmentIndent", 10) etc. but all my guesses so far result in a runtime error:

> BASIC runtime error. Property or method not found: AlignmentIndent

[image]

**So my question is:**
Is it possible to set the Text Alignment Indent using a macro?
Is there a way to find property names, where can I find documentation for Libreoffice macro's?
Is there a way to auto complete code when typing, similar to intellisense in VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is it possible to set the Text Alignment Indent using a macro?

Yes. You need to be setting `com.sun.star.table.CellProperties`. The property is:

> `ParaIndent`
>
> The indentation of the cell’s content (in 0.01 mm) as a Short Integer.

See below for source document.

---

#### Where can I find documentation for Libreoffice macro's?

At [OpenOffice.org Macros Explained](http://www.pitonyak.org/OOME_3_0.pdf) by Andrew Pitonyak [warning: pdf link].

Comment: Thanks, but when I set oCell.ParaIndent = 10 there is no runtime error at least, but nothing happens. Also, is there any other documentation besides this PDF on a personal website?

Comment: Sorry I see now the value is not in pt units like in the GUI but in 0.01 mm. For 10pt the corresponding value should be set to 353. Is there a better way to convert from pt to 0.01mm? So other than `oCell.ParaIndent = (10 * 35.28)` ?

Comment: No idea. I don't really use the LibreOffice macros.

Comment: The PDF is actually a book, which the author is still working on. I don't know of any other such detailed documentation on macros.